# Are the specifications of a TL07X op amp better with a higher voltage , then what it is tested with and what it says its in datasheet?

Tags: operational-amplifier

It seems a TL07X class op amp is tested at +/-15 Volts , and that is where they get all the specifications from, when the op amp is tested at this particular voltage.

The max voltage seems to be +/-18 volts for these op amps, and I am wondering if it would have better performance at this higher voltage?

Like for example , these op amps usually have a GBW listed at 3 MHz , tested at the +/-15 volts, if the voltage would be set at +/-18 volts maximum, would be the GBW be slightly higher then the 3 MHz? I do know its not a recommendation for Tl07X class op amps to use them at the maximum voltage.

I am also wondering about the various other specifications as well and if the other specs would be slightly improved too?

Comment: Just get a better op-amp if the current device is running out of steam.

Comment: From section 6.2 (Absolute Maximum Ratings) in the datasheet "These are stress ratings only, and **functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions beyond those indicated under Recommended Operating Conditions is not implied**". So no, you shouldn't expect improved performance by violating the operating spec of the device.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, max. V for spec compliance and reliability is 15 V. Of course the device can survive 18 V, but it is intended that this might be brief (undefined), and is really only defined to be for survival, not functionality.

GBW will not change appreciably with a higher supply voltage. GBW depends on transistor parameters and bias currents. The internal bias currents are generated by a circuit that is quite independent of supply voltage. While you might observe some minuscule change in GBW with supply voltage increase, this will be much smaller than any part-part variations and you can't really depend on it. It is even possible that the slightly increased temperature that results from a higher supply voltage *decreases* the GBW.

Comment: what about at lower voltages what if you use a voltage that is way lower then the +/-15 volts tested ?  like what if you used +/-5 volts instead? I am guessing that the GBW may drop a bit.

Answer (score 0):

SHort Answer: No , performance is not improved between 30V and 36V max differential supply range.

Due to constant current source regulators, to ought to be constant.

Figure 6-48. Large-Signal Differential Voltage Amplification and
Phase Shift vs Frequency indicates the typical curve of GBW from  +/-5 to +/-15V. So you should stay within this region.

Also, higher voltage swings of dV/dt with capacitive loading will become slew-rate are limited.